Metadata service class generated by WSDL to Apex gives following PMD errors
I am building an appexchange app. Metadata service class generated by WSDL to Apex gives me the following PMD errors -:

The local variable name 'response_map_x' doesn't Code Style
The method parameter name 'type_x' doesn't match Code Style
The instance field name 'AllOrNoneHeader_hns' Code Style
The instance field name 'timeout_x' doesn't match Code Style

Can I add my apex class in False Positive while submitting our appexchange app for Security review?

While having and enforcing naming conventions in your project is always good, you don't have to worry about it when submitting an app for security review, so you could just ignore those warnings. You could also define your own ruleset file containing only what really matters for security review and use that one to check your app before submitting it

The entire code style category is irrelevant for security review submissions and you should restrict the scan to the set of rules required for app exchange submissions, as mentioned in the documentation:

In addition to the base PMD engine, Code Analyzer also includes a custom PMD variant, pmd-appexchange. The rules included in pmd-appexchange helps you prepare your managed packages for security review.
The pmd-appexchange engine is disabled by default. To run a PMD scan with the AppExchange ruleset, run sf scanner run with the --engine pmd-appexchange flag.

